# Segmentation fault before main with pcl::ExtractIndices (pcl, ROS, catkin)

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, ros, catkin

I am attempting to run the following in C++:

```
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include "pcl/pcl_base.h"
#include "pcl/PointIndices.h"
#include "pcl/conversions.h"
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace pcl;

void myFunction() {
     ...
     ExtractIndices<PointXYZ> rangefilter;
     ...
}

int main() {
     cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

The code compiles, but I get a segmentation fault as soon as I run it; the cout statement isn't executed.  Notice I don't actually even call myFunction() in main.  The only error message is

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I comment out the ExtractIndices line in myFunction, the problem goes away and the code runs fine:

```
     // ExtractIndices<PointXYZ> rangefilter;
```

I am running this on Ubuntu with ROS and compiling it with catkin_make, if that helps.

I'd really appreciate some help debugging this, as I've been stuck on this problem for a while. Thanks for reading!

Comment: where does the debugger say it goes bang?

Comment: The reason for crashes before `main` is mostly due to global or static objects being constructed before main() has run, and the construction of these objects causes the error.  You need to get a stack trace of the functions called that led up to the crash.

Comment: [Start here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help from the commenters, I was able to find the issue. I did a backtrace with gdb and googled the output:

```
boost::math::lanczos::lanczos_initializer<boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64, long double>::init::init()
```

Then found this: http://answers.ros.org/question/194699/segmentation-fault-when-using-correspondencerejectorsampleconsensus/

Which says that you can't use C++11 with PCL, so I removed this line from my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

And it worked!